# html multiple fields differentiation on a form

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

i'm new to website development and i'm unsure of the technical word for this but i have a form with fields on it e.g.

```
User Info
Name 
Surname
Address

User Modules
Module Name 
Module Day 
....
```

At present i have these fields in a form showing one after another, there is no separation between them. Is there a function in html that i can use to make the form a bit more readable? e.g. (like a group separation?) i know i can just indent the title but would like to know the proper way to do this.

```
User Info
    Name 
    Surname
    Address

User Modules
    Module Name 
    Module Day 
    ....
```

Comment: This is exactly what CSS is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [FIELDSET](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp) and a [LEGEND](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_legend.asp).